# Xeon Phi swap from host's tmpfs

Tags: linux, virtualization, swap, ram

I want to use swap on Xeon Phi (mic0) using RAM from the host

On the host:

```
# free -m
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:        129022      60312      68710          0       1092      50078
-/+ buffers/cache:       9141     119880
Swap:            0          0          0
```

Running this command on the host:

```
# mount -t ramfs ramfs /mnt/ramfs/
# dd bs=512M if=/dev/zero of=/mnt/ramfs/ram1 count=48
# echo /mnt/ramfs/ram1 >/sys/class/mic/mic0/virtblk_file
# df -a | grep ramfs
/mnt/ramfs              0          0          0    - /mnt/ramfs
# vim  /etc/mpss/default.conf # add:
ExtraCommandLine "vfs_read_optimization=on" 
ExtraCommandLine "vfs_write_optimization=on"
# service mpss stop
# micctrl --resetconfig
# service mpss start
```

Then run on the mic0:

```
# modprobe mic_virtblk 
# mkswap /dev/vda
# swapon /dev/vda
# free -m
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          7697        574       7123          0          0        145
-/+ buffers/cache:        428       7268
Swap:        24575          0      24575
```

How can i ensure that the swap already connected on the host's RAM?

And if it's already connected to host's RAM, why it's become so slow when using swap on the Xeon Phi?

the testing code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>   
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>

long timediff(clock_t t1, clock_t t2) {
    long elapsed;
    elapsed = ((double)t2 - t1) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC * 1000;
    return elapsed;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    clock_t t1, t2;
    int max = 100;
    int mb = 0;
    int size = 256;
    char* buffer;

    if(argc > 1)
        max = atoi(argv[1]);

    t1 = clock();
    while((buffer=malloc(size*1024*1024)) != NULL && mb != max) {
        memset(buffer, 0, size*1024*1024);
        ++mb;
        t2 = clock();
        printf("Allocated %.2f GB in %ld ms\n", mb * size / 1024.0, timediff(t1, t2) );
        t1 = t2;
    }      
return 0;
}
```

compile using: `icc swaptest.c -o swaptest -mmic`

the result:

```
# ./swaptest 
Allocated 0.25 GB in 260 ms
Allocated 0.50 GB in 269 ms
...
Allocated 6.75 GB in 269 ms
Allocated 7.00 GB in 260 ms
Allocated 7.25 GB in 470 ms
Allocated 7.50 GB in 1819 ms
Allocated 7.75 GB in 2060 ms
Allocated 8.00 GB in 2420 ms
Allocated 8.25 GB in 2820 ms
Allocated 8.50 GB in 2750 ms
Allocated 8.75 GB in 2300 ms
Allocated 9.00 GB in 1380 ms
Allocated 9.25 GB in 1530 ms
Allocated 9.50 GB in 3400 ms
Allocated 9.75 GB in 3800 ms
Allocated 10.00 GB in 3940 ms
Allocated 10.25 GB in 3579 ms
Allocated 10.50 GB in 5050 ms
Allocated 10.75 GB in 5029 ms
Allocated 11.00 GB in 5130 ms
Allocated 11.25 GB in 4770 ms
Allocated 11.50 GB in 3719 ms
Allocated 11.75 GB in 2300 ms
Allocated 12.00 GB in 3619 ms
```

and so on..

compared to on Host system:

```
$ ./a.out 
Allocated 0.25 GB in 140 ms
Allocated 0.50 GB in 170 ms
Allocated 0.75 GB in 160 ms
Allocated 1.00 GB in 160 ms
...
Allocated 23.75 GB in 130 ms
Allocated 24.00 GB in 130 ms
Allocated 24.25 GB in 130 ms
Allocated 24.50 GB in 130 ms
Allocated 24.75 GB in 130 ms
Allocated 25.00 GB in 120 ms
```

when below swap: 256MB in 269 ms is about 951MB/s

when using swap: 256MB in 5.13 seconds is about 48.7MB/s, its much slower than benchmark that shown on https://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2014/01/07/improving-file-io-performance-on-intel-xeon-phi (at least ~360MB/s), is this behavior intended?

I'm using `icc (ICC) 14.0.2 20140120` (parallel_studio_xe_2013_sp1_update2) and `mpss-3.2.1` for Xeon Phi [5110P](http://ark.intel.com/products/71992/Intel-Xeon-Phi-Coprocessor-5110P-8GB-1_053-GHz-60-core) series (rev 11)